# App terminated when trying to add child value from a variable in Firebase. Swift 4.0

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9, swift4.1

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

[image]

String was empty at first but when i press next the value from form 1 is automatically assigned to these variables

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let registerationVC = segue.destination as! RegistrationViewController
    registerationVC.displayNameText = self.displayNameText
    registerationVC.emailOrPhoneText = self.emailOrPhoneText
    registerationVC.registrationMethod = self.currentRegistrationType
}
```

Comment: Don't post screen shot of code copy paste instead

Comment: It looks like your self.emailPhoneText is empty string

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I added the code where values are assigned  to that empty string

Comment: Put break point exact before app crashes and print all values on console

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya https://imgur.com/a/pWvCnNJ
Here it is printing those values

Comment: Nvm figured it out, since email contains '.' and child name should not contain '.'